# Yii framework : controllerMap can 'rename' url, how about the view

Tags: php, yii

My situation :

I have a these MVC file :

```
controllers\BookController.php  
views\book\index.php
models\book.php
```

Then my client tell me they want to change the url

- into "http://examplate.com/theBook/someAction"
- instead of "http://examplate.com/Book/someAction"

**A. controllerMap**

I can change the it by using "controllerMap", but it say "cannot find the requested view" which I need to rename the view folder... which is dumd.

**B. urlManager**

When I try urlManager  :

```
'theBook' => 'Book'                          //works
'theBook/<action:\w+>' => 'Book/<action>'    //not working
```

---

Is there any way to change it all the MCV's routing url name, without rename my existing folder ?

Answer (score 0):

In config -> main.php, change the following

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'caseSensitive'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(

            '/Book/<action>' => 'theBook/<action>/'
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: 'theBook/<action:\w+>' => 'Book/<action>' is not working

Comment: try '/Book/<action>' => 'theBook/<action>/' .You don't want to add w+

Comment: or else '<Book:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<theBook>/<action>',

Comment: Are you getting the result now?